# Make sure function is finished. Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have the below function. I read several Json files and parse them and want to include them into an array and return that array.Problem is how do I make sure that the function really have read the 5 files on the harddrive? I have tried check if variable `i` equals `fileNameListLength-1` and check if the function have finished that way but it didn't work, the for loop was finished before the `fs.readFile` functions were finished. So how would you solve this?. Sorry for possible duplicate of question.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var urlToInfo = '/home/user/data';

function getRawData() {
    var fileNameList = ['file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3', 'file_4', 'file_5'];
    var fileNameListLength = fileNameList.length;
    var rawDataArray = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < fileNameListLength; i++) {
        var url = urlToInfo + "/Data/" + fileNameList[i] + ".json";
        fs.readFile(url, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            try {
                var portalData = JSON.parse(data);
                rawDataArray[fileNameList[i]] = portalData;
            } catch (e) {
                // Error parsing JSON data
                console.log("Error Parsing Json data.");
                console.log(e);
            }
        });

    }
    //Make sure that all files have been read and that the rawDataArray contains all info
    //return rawDataArray
}
```

Comment: The simplest solution is to do that synchronously, e,g, `readFileSync`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the `async` library and using the `eachSeries` function.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var urlToInfo = '/home/user/data';
var rawArray = [];

async.eachSeries(fileNameList, function(fileName,callback){
    var url = urlToInfo + "/Data/" + fileNameList[i] + ".json";
    fs.readFile(url, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        try {
            var portalData = JSON.parse(data);
            rawArray.push(portalData);
        } catch (e) {
            // Error parsing JSON data
            console.log("Error Parsing Json data.");
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
}, function(err){
    console.log('the reading of all files finished');
    console.log('array',rawArray);
});
```

This will execute the function in series and fill the array when all the iterator functions are called, the callback function will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the condition in the readFile cb, this should be easy to do.

But I suggest you can have a try at promise.

```
var fsp = require('fs-promise');

var files = ['foo1', 'foo2'];

// weird, files.map(fsp.readFile) does not work.
Promise.all(files.map(function (foo) {
    return fsp.readFile(foo);
})).then(function (results) {
    // process data
}, function (err) {
    // error processing
})
```